# Initializing KafkaProducer object once and use the same object by all the samplers in a Jmeter script

Tags: apache-kafka, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to implement a scenario as mentioned below :
I have to create a load test-script my async APIs that are publishing and consuming events from Kafka topics.
In this script there are multiple samplers that are publishing messages on different topics and currently they are creating a producer client in each of the samplers and then closing it there.
To improve the overall performance of this script and also bring the script closer to real-life scenario , we want to initialize KafkaProducer only once at the start of the test and close it towards the end.
So I have implemented a solution like this :

```
TestPlan
  ThreadGroup
    1.JSR223Sampler to initialize the Kafka Producer 
    2.Another JSR223 Sampler to publish a message on a topic
```

using same Kafka Producer initialized above

But the problem is , when I save the Kafka Producer object in Sampler1 using vars.putObject() function and get this object in Sampler2 using vars.getObject function , it returns me an object of java.lang.String class in Sampler2.
And if I try to cast it now in Sampler2 , it doesn't work and it throws ClassCastException

Sampler1 script :

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;

 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("bootstrap.servers", vars.get('bootstrapServer'));
 props.put("transactional.id", "my-transactional-id");
 Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer());
 vars.putObject("producer",producer);
```

Sampler2 script :

```
`KafkaProducer producer1 =  vars.getObject("producer") as KafkaProducer;
ProducerRecord<String, String> record  = new ProducerRecord<String, String>('REPO-Asset-Partner-QueryRequest', '', "{\"data\":\"{\\\"assetSearchCriteria\\\":[{\\\"attribute\\\":\\\"category\\\",\\\"operator\\\":\\\"EQ\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"SYSTEM\\\"}]}\"}")
record.headers().add(new RecordHeader('authorization', bear.getBytes()))
record.headers().add(new RecordHeader('ce_id', vars.get('searchIndex').getBytes()))
record.headers().add(new RecordHeader('ce_type', 'com.fico.repo.ms.asset.events.message.partner.query.AssetSearch'.getBytes()))
record.headers().add(new RecordHeader('ce_time', vars.get('time').getBytes()))
record.headers().add(new RecordHeader('requestId', vars.get('searchCorelation').getBytes()))
producer1.send(record)
producer1.close()`
```

Exception:

```
Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer'
```

I am still facing ClassCastException .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `producer` variable is an empty string so I would recommend checking the element where you're declaring it.

If you're showing the full code you're missing at least an [import](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_imports) statement for the [StringSerializer](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringSerializer.html)

So check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries and use [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to inspect the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which are defined for this thread (virtual user)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with available [DI-Kafkameter](https://github.com/rollno748/di-kafkameter#readme) plugin which is available in Plugins manager.
[image]

That should ideally create the connection only once and makes the life easier for you.